# Does anyone know how to disable the Right-Click Open in New Windows feature in Google Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome

By default in Google Chrome Browser, on embedded links; there is a Right-Click menu that has Open link in New Tab and Open Link in New Window as the first two options.
It is annoying to have a new Google Chrome Browser window open when accidentally touching the New Window option rather than the New Tab option.
Is there any way to remove the unwanted option from that list? This could also apply in reverse for some people who prefer new windows over new tabs.

Additionally if anyone knows how to do this in other browsers, I am open to switching browsers to get this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think (95%) you will find that the answer to your question is no, at least for Chrome, Chromium Edge in Windows and Firefox in Linux.

The first option is New Tab (and at the top), the bottom option is Incognito or Private (and at the bottom) for all three. If I am only normally careful, I rarely pick the wrong option.

Short of an extension I am not aware of, the order is apparently built in and removing one of the options is therefore not possible.

I did find that you can disable redirection in Firefox for a new tab, but that is not what you are looking for. So my research here has not produced results.